# Manually communicate on an USB bus

Tags: microcontroller, usb, signal-processing, usb-host

I'm using an [MBED LPC1768](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/mbed-LPC1768/) as a UC and I'm trying to communicate with a USB Device (a random hub) just to read the device descriptor.

I'm quite a novice in electronics.

I've connected + and - to UC 5V and GND, and D+ / D- to standards Digital/IO pins. I've also hook them up with 10K resistors to ground.
When I plug in the device, I can see D+ going up, so it means this is a high speed device.

I've try to send reset (for 20ms), then some manually encoded frames, but after sending two frames (sync / data / eop), and changing the IO pins to "input", nothings happens: bus stays in idle state (D+ up, D- down).

Here is my code:

```c
#include "mbed.h"
#include "crc.h"

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
DigitalInOut dplus(p21);
DigitalInOut dminus(p22);

void sendBits(int bits, int length);
void waitNbit(int n);
void sendPacket();
void sendEOP();
void sendReset();
void sendSync();
void setJ();
void setK();
void sendCRC(uint8_t crc);

int lastSentK; // For NRZI
int sentOneCounter; // For bit stuffing

void send0()
{
    sentOneCounter = 0;
    if (lastSentK) setJ();
    else setK();
    lastSentK = !lastSentK;
}

void send1()
{
    sentOneCounter++;
    waitNbit(1);
    if (sentOneCounter == 6) // Bit stuffing
    {
        send0();
    }
}

void sendCRC16(uint16_t crc)
{
    // send msb first
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if (crc & (1 << (16 - i))) send1();
        else send0();
    }
}

void sendCRC(uint8_t crc)
{
    // send msb first
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (crc & (1 << (4 - i))) send1();
        else send0();
    }
}

void sendBytes(uint8_t* bytes, int length)
{
    // Send lsb first
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        //printf("Sending %02X\r\n", bytes[i]);
        sendBits(bytes[i], 8);
    }
}

void sendBits(int bits, int length)
{
    // Send lsb first
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (bits & 0x01) send1();
        else send0();
        bits = bits >> 1;
    }
}

void waitNbit(int n)
{
    wait_ns(n * 83); // 83 ns per byte (12MHz)
}

void sendEOP()
{
    dplus = 0;
    dminus = 0;
    waitNbit(2);
    setJ();
}

void sendReset()
{
    dplus = 0;
    dminus = 0;
    wait_us(20 * 1000); // > 10ms
}

void sendSync()
{
    // KJKJKJKK
    setK();
    setJ();
    setK();
    setJ();
    setK();
    setJ();
    setK();
    setK();
    lastSentK = 1;
}

void setJ()
{
    dplus = 1;
    dminus = 0;
    waitNbit(1);
}

void setK()
{
    dplus = 0;
    dminus = 1;
    waitNbit(1);
}

void sendTokenPacket()
{
    sendSync();
    //Send packet data

    sendBits(0b00101101, 8); // SETUP PID
    sendBits(0, 7); // Address
    sendBits(0, 4); // Endpoint
    sendCRC(0x08);

    sendEOP();
}

void sendSetupDataPacket()
{
    sendSync();
    //Send packet data

    uint8_t data[] = {
        0x80, // request type (direction=device to host?? type=standard recipient=device)
        0x06, // bRequest GET_DESCRIPTOR
        0x00, // Descriptor index
        0x01, // Descriptor type (DEVICE)
        0x00, // Language id
        0x00, // Language id
        0x12, // Length (allow device to send 18 bytes)
        0x00  // ?
    };
    uint16_t crc = compute_crc16(data, sizeof(data));

    uint8_t finalData[20];

    finalData[0] = 0b11000011; // Data0 pid
    memcpy(finalData + 1, data, sizeof(data));

    sendBytes(finalData, sizeof(data) + 1); // Data
    sendCRC16(crc);

    sendEOP();
}

void listen()
{
    dplus.input();
    dminus.input();
    uint8_t old_dplus = dplus.read();
    uint8_t old_dminus = dminus.read();
    //pc.printf("Status (%x ; %x).\r\n", old_dminus, old_dplus);
    while (true)
    {
        if (dminus.read() != old_dminus || dplus.read() != old_dplus)
        {
            pc.printf("Change (%x->%x %x->%x).\r\n", old_dminus, dminus.read(), old_dplus, dplus.read());
            old_dminus = dminus.read();
            old_dplus = dplus.read();
        }
        waitNbit(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    dplus.input();
    dminus.input();
    pc.printf("Started\r\n");

    while (true)
    {
        wait_us(1000 * 500); //0.5s

        if (dplus.read() == 1) // Pulled high by full speed device
        {
            dplus.output();
            dminus.output();
            sendReset();
            sendTokenPacket();
            sendSetupDataPacket();
            listen();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What could be off, and how can I debug that?

Comment: Why the bit-banging? The MCU has USB peripheral that can act as USB host.

Comment: @Justme Yes, but I'd like to reimplement the most possible thing myself to understand how the stuff is working. Is it possible to reimplement USB that way?

Comment: If you ask if it is possible, it should be. I know people implement bitbang USB devices but I have never seen bitbang USB host (it may still exist). It just makes no sense given you have the USB peripheral device, so you don't have to implement the bit level stuff yourself, and can concentrate on the high level application.

Comment: @Justme There's no high level application, the whole project is me trying to understand how the USB protocol works as a host, from the bit/electronical/signaling stuff.

Comment: USB is quite an undertaking for "a novice."  What speed is the USB bus running at? Micro is 96MHz, perhaps micro isn't fast enough to receive data from user code. Kudos for trying to understand it, but to actually use USB, the peripheral (and USB stack/libraries) is the only practical way to go for many reasons.

Comment: Sounds like the USB is running at 12Mhz, which is why I sleep 92ns between each bit. I'm not trying to be practical or efficient, if I just get some responses from the USB device I'll be happy and call it a day :D

Comment: 12 Mbps is 83.333 ns bit time. Frequency tolerance of FS USB devices is about 5000 ppm, or 0.5%. You have your frequency off by ~10%.

Answer (score 2):

> I've try to send reset (for 20ms), then some manually encoded frames,
>   but after sending two frames (sync / data / eop), and changing the IO
>   pins to "input", nothings happens: bus stays in idle state (D+ up, D-
>   down).

To begin, your way of "manually control" serial interface is called "bit-banging". FYI.

Then, you need to do quite a bit more than what you described.

First, you have to start a CONTINUOUS stream of frame packets on 1 ms interval, with incremented frame counter.

Second, to get any response from a USB device, you need to send a valid USB request. The first request is usually the "GET_DESCRIPTOR" from default control pipe (address 0 endpoint 0).

This would be your first challenge.

So far I have not heard of any bit-bang implementation of full-speed (12 mbps) USB protocol on ARM-level processors. There are LS implementations though.

The only [successful bit-banging implementation of 12-mbps USB](https://scanlime.org/2010/04/its-alive-bit-banging-full-speed-usb-host-for-the-propeller/) I know of is on [Parallax/Propeller MCU](https://www.parallax.com/microcontrollers/propeller), which is a symmetrical 8-core 32-bit processor running at 80 MHz, with special IO access features.

> I can see D+ going up, so it means this is a high speed device.

No, it means that it could be either FS or HS device, depending on whether the device asserts Chirp-K during USB bus reset. FYI.